# Testing SP-Initiated Saml 2.0 SSO: is there a IDP that supports dynamic ACS URL?

Tags: testing, saml-2.0

I'm currently trying to setup tests to test my application's SP-initiated SSO. This test will be run in different environments, and especially in kubernetes as well, where the recipient/destination URL will be dynamic and different (ie: http://localhost:5000/sso, https://k8s-server-1.com/sso, https://k8s-server-2.com/sso, etc.)

I've looked into free developer accounts with OKTA and OneLogin, and it seems neither supports dynamic ACS URLs. Short of investing time writing a mock SAML IDP of some sort, is there any other resources I can use to test my SP-initiated SSO flow?

Answer (score 0):

The ACS url is part of the security. If someone can spoof a SAML request with any ACS url they can get attributes sent anywhere. It's the same concept as `replyUrl` in OIDC. Each valid one needs to be registered in the SP metadata.

If you know all the ACS urls you can add them to the SP's metadata the IdP consumes. Use `index` for each one.

```
<AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://localhost:5000/sso" index="0" isDefault="true" />
<AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://k8s-server-1.com/sso" index="1" isDefault="false" />
```